# Plugins configuration file for Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, vimrc, macvim, vim-plugins

I'm quite new to Vim, and, since I'm writing my very own `.vimrc` file, I was wondering if there is a way to store all the commands relative to a certain plugin configuration in one external file, in order to make the original `.vimrc` file less dense, and how can I call that file in my `.vimrc` file. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to say that I'm currently using Pathogen as plugin manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate settings for plugins in several files, and include them in .vimrc

For example:

```
" My Plugin settings {
if filereadable(expand('~/.vim/my.plugin.settings.vim'))
  source ~/.vim/my.plugin.settings.vim
endif
" }
```

Comment: Thank you! Where I have to put the if block? At the beginning of the file?

Comment: I figured out where to put that block, thank you again!

Comment: You can put it instead of the block with plugin settings. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If Pathogen is not registering plugins before `$HOME/.vim` (which is extremely unlikely), you could simply drop your configuration file into `$HOME/.vim/plugin/`. That's all. No need to test anything (*), nor to be explicit. IOW: no need to write anything in your `.vimrc` to configure your plugins if you use a plugin manager.

(*) Actually, there is really no need to test anything: `:runtime my.plugin.settings.vim` wouldn't have barked at you if the file wasn't there, and it would have sourced if it were.